# How do I convert an integer method into a string method in Java?

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a dice program and I am need the output to be a string of 'One', 'Two', 'Three', etc. It is currently printing an output of 0 but that is because my OutputDice method is incorrect. When I take it out it passes the arguments as integers, but I need them as strings. How do I do that?

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

    private int Value;

    public void setValue(int diceValue)
    {
           Value = diceValue;
    }
    public int getValue()
    {
           return Value;
    }
    public void roll()
    {
         Random rand = new Random();
            Value = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
    public void OutputDice()
    {
        switch (Value)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("One");
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Two");
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Three");
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Four");
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Five");
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Six");
        }   
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DiceRoll {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Dice firstDie = new Dice();
        Dice secondDie = new Dice();

        firstDie.OutputDice();
        secondDie.OutputDice();

        System.out.println("Dice 1: "+ firstDie.getValue());
        System.out.println("Dice 2: "+ secondDie.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: you are forgetting to call `roll`

Comment: If you do not roll your dice, I do not think it will get you any number. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also never assign a value to your dice. You need to call the `roll()` method before displaying the values. Also, With switch case statements you need to include breaks after your cases like so

```
public void OutputDice()
{
    switch (Value)
    {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("One");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Two");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Three");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Four");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Five");
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Six");
        break;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. It was a simple oversight. Here is what I got for the answer:

```
import java.util.Random;

    public class Dice {

        private int Value;

        public void setValue(int diceValue){
               Value = diceValue;
        }
        public int getValue(){
               return Value;
        }
        public void roll(){
             Random rand = new Random();
                Value = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        }
        public void OutputDice(){
            switch (Value)
            {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("One");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Two");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Three");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Four");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Five");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Six");
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
```

and

```
public class BrandonAssignment4 {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Dice firstDie = new Dice();
        Dice secondDie = new Dice();

        firstDie.roll();
        secondDie.roll();

        firstDie.OutputDice();
        secondDie.OutputDice();
    }
}
```